# Load a local web with WebView in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, webview

In a WPF application, how can I load a simple web, but that calls multiple JavaScript, CSS, etc... Hosted on the hard drive?
With `WebBrowser` the web application does not work, it gives many JavaScript errors, and with `WebView` I have not been able to load a url of the type `file:///c:/folder/web.html`

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the file to your output directory and use the `NavigateToLocal` method of the `WebView`:

```
const string LocalFilePath = "web.html";
System.IO.File.Copy("c:/folder/web.html", LocalFilePath);
webView.NavigateToLocal(LocalFilePath);
```

Or you could load the contents of the file into a `string` and use the `NavigateToString` method:

```
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:/folder/web.html");
webView.NavigateToString(s);
```

Comment: With `NavigateToLocal` it works for me, but it warns me that this method is obsolete and that I use `NavigateToLocalStream` and I can't get it to work

Comment: @PanzerIhnen: Suppress the warning then. Or use `NavigateToString`.